# Can you numerically solve the geodesic equation in the most general setting?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, geodesic

I'm currently trying to solve the geodesic equation in the most general setting possible. A curve $\gamma(s) = (\gamma^0(s), \gamma^1(s), \gamma^2(s), \gamma^3(s))$ satisfies the geodesic equation if

$$\frac{d^2\gamma^i}{ds^2} + \sum_{a,b}\Gamma_{ab}^i(\gamma(s))\frac{d\gamma^a}{ds}\frac{d\gamma^b}{ds} = 0$$
for $i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. Making the substitution $\tau^i = d(\gamma^i)/ds$ you can reduce the system to one twice as big of the form
$$\frac{d\tau^i}{ds} + \sum_{a,b}\Gamma_{ab}^i(\gamma(s))\frac{d\gamma^a}{ds}\frac{d\gamma^b}{ds} = 0$$
I tried to solve it as one usually does (that is, writing it in the form $y' = f(s, y)$) but, although factoring $\tau'$ is easy, one cannot do such a thing for $d\gamma^i/ds$: assuming one has the Levi-Civita connection (that is, $\Gamma^i_{ab} = \Gamma^i_{ba}$) one ends up with something of the form
$$a(s) + b(s)\frac{d\gamma^i}{ds} + \Gamma_{ii}^i(\gamma(s))\left(\frac{d\gamma^i}{ds}\right)^2 = 0$$
**Is there a method for solving one of these ODEs?**; in summary, can one numerically solve an ODE of the form $(y')^2 + p(t)y' + q(t) = 0$?

Comment: If $p,q$ can be assume analytic then my intuition would be to expand $y,p$ and $q$ in $t$ to obtain a recursion which can be solved order by order to arbitrary precision. This becomes your numerical approximation.

If analyticity is too strong, you can do an expansion within the class of $C^k$ functions but things get messier of course.

Comment: @SDK yeah, but what about $y'$?, wouldn't you get some sort of quadratic scheme because of the $(y')^2$?; on the other hand, I failed to notice that by the change $\tau^i = d\gamma^i/ds$ you really just end up with $d\tau^i/ds + \sum_{a,b}\Gamma_{ab}^i \tau^a\tau^b = 0$, maybe this system is easier, by just focusing on the $\tau$s. What do you think?